# add inline image to a message sent with swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Please excuse my php but, Im using Swiftmailer to send emails from a clients website. They've requested to add an image or two as a signature etc and so looking at the swiftmailer spec here

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

They suggest either adding an inline image like this

```
$message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('http://site.tld/image here'))
```

or like this(in 2 steps)

```
$cid = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('image here'));
```

then in the emails body section add

```
<img src="' . $cid . '" alt="Image" />'
```

Both steps ive tried but to no avail. When i hit the send email button, i get this error which i dont quite know what to make of it.

```
Call to a member function embed() on a non-object in /home/content/78/5152878/html/4testing/erase/ask-doc-proc2.php on line 89
```

The only thing i added to my already working code and email was the image code directly from the example in the docs pages. This error obviously prevents the email from being sent. if i remove it then it sends emails fine. Since i need to add an image to this,

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

***edit: this is the portion where the email is built and sent***
$cid= $message->embed(Swift_EmbeddedFile::fromPath('http://myforecyte.com/dev/pic.jpg'));

```
->setTo( $docEmail)

->setBody("Hello" . "\r\n\r\n" .  
$fullName . " has visited MyForeCYTE.com. Upon their visit they have requested to learn more about the test. \r\n\r\n" . 
"Please visit www.ClarityWomensHealth.com to find out more about The ForeCYTE Breast Health Test, or call our customer support line at 1 (877) 722-6339.  \r\n\r\n" .
"We look forward to hearing from you. \r\n\r\n" .
"Thank You," , 'text/plain')

->addPart("Hello" . ",</b><br/><br/>" . 
"<b>" . $fullName . "</b> has visited www.MyForeCYTE.com. Upon their visit they have requested to learn more about the test. <br/>" . 
"Please visit www.ClarityWomensHealth.com to find out more about The ForeCYTE Breast Health Test, or call our customer support line at 1 (877) 722-6339.<br/> " . 
"We look forward to hearing from you. <br/><br/><br/>" . "<img src='" . $cid. "' alt='pic'/>" .

"Thank you " , 'text/html')
;
```

Comment: Since you are not showing the filename for `image here`, it's a bit hard to tell if it's properly formatted.

Comment: Can you show the complete code where you build the message?

Comment: What's on `line 89` of `ask-doc-proc2.php` file?

Comment: To answer your questions @ Fred, the "image here" is "filename.jpg". As far as "whats on line 89, its this , " $cid = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('http://myforecyte.com/dev/Ariana_Perez.jpg')); "

Comment: @somdow Have you tried adding `http://` or if you're on `www` - `http://www.` before `myforecyte.com`?

Comment: Hi Fred, yep ive dont that but still the same message.

Comment: Is `http://myforecyte.com/dev/Ariana_Perez.jpg` the file you wish to have displayed? If so, try making it all lowercase. Sometimes servers play mean tricks with file conventions as such. I'm picking at straws here I know, but am trying to go by `process of elimination`.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump( );`?

Comment: No i appreciate it @Fred. I went ahead and changed "Ariana_Perez.jpg" to "pic.jpg" and nope, no good.

Comment: Do a `var_dump();` for `$message` and `$cid` and show the results.

Comment: When i do var_dump($message); or the same for cid, nothing prints on the page, i still get the same error

Comment: Are all your paths set right? I'm baffled.

Comment: yeah i mean, im stumped too. The only path on the whole email is the one for the image which is this one 'http://myforecyte.com/dev/pic.jpg' ....im lost aswell

Comment: when i remove that line for the picture, the email sends fine

Comment: now since when doing var dump, since it doesnt show me anything , could that be a problem in its self?

Comment: Maybe. From what I found so far about an empty var_dump result is and I quote "You most likely have html tags in your string that are being rendered by the browser." You may have single quotes where double quotes are required, hard to say. Are you headers set to send out as `text/html`?

Comment: What about `display_errors`, is it "on"?

Comment: i went ahead and added the rest of the code that handles the email build

Comment: Ok. Well, one last resort. What's your PHP file(s) encoded as? If it's `UTF-8`, is it `with` or `without` the `BOM`? Am picking at another straw, but not leaving it out of the equation. I doubt it but worth a shot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After all the running around i found an alternate solution. Swiftmailer allows 2 methods in which to perform the same thing.

one is the embed() function

and the other one is the attach() function

so to the code above, i removed the "embed()" since it wasn't working for me and added these 2 lines below and it works

```
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('path to image here.jpg')  
->setDisposition('inline'));
```

and it worked 100%

Comment: you called it on `$message` like `$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('path to image here.jpg')  
->setDisposition('inline'));` ?

Answer (score 8):

None of the answers really worked for me. I had to include inline images, using CID. What I had to do, to make it work:

```
$attachment = Swift_Image::newInstance($data, $filename, $mimeType)
    ->setDisposition('inline');

$cid = $message->embed($attachment); // Generates "cid:something"
```

Important part is using Swift_Image class. Then the image in html should be:

```
<img src="cid:something" ... />
```

I think this solution works without doing something hacky with swiftmailer (ver. 5.4.2). It is exactly how the documentation says.

Remember to test multiple email clients (gmail, thunderbird, apple mail, web clients...) if the inline images work. For example using Swift_Attachment, inline images showed in gmail, but not in some web clients. Using Swift_Image, it worked everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer doesn't work (version tested: 5.4.2).
(Mine works but could be perfected)

Instead, looking inside the "Original" (Gmail: Show Original) I've found that swiftmailer is omitting adding 2 headers to the attachment, namely:

```
Content-ID: <ABC123>
X-Attachment-Id: ABC123
```

ABC123 is the cid we have to put in the body where we want the inline to be showed:

So thanks to [this question](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9236/solved-kohana-mail-adding-a-custom-header-to-an-attachment/p1): I found the way to fix it for swiftmailer (that is even against swiftmailer documentation, but it works while theirs do not)

this is the final (ugly) code:

```
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath('image.jpg')->setDisposition('inline');
$attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-ID', '<ABC123>');
$attachment->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Attachment-Id', 'ABC123');
$cid = $message->embed($attachment);
$img = '<img src="cid:ABC123"/>';
$html = "
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
$img
</body>
</html>
";
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
```

Comment: This is a working solution, thank you very much for this piece of code!

Comment: Thank you very much, working for me in Laravel 5.8. One thing - assigning to `$cid` is confusing, since you don't need this variable.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question (with an accepted answer), but for anyone having the same problem, the [`Swift_Image::fromPath($image_path)`](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/class-Swift_Image.html) method expects the image path to be local (a filesystem path):

```
Swift_Image::fromPath("/local/path/to/image.jpg");
// Local path = great success
```

Thus the below will fail if your image path is external (starting with `https://`, etc.):

```
Swift_Image::fromPath("https://external.path/to/image.jpg");
// External path = epic fail
```

For external images, you should use:

```
# Load the image file
$data = file_get_contents($image_path);
# Get the filename
$filename = explode("?",basename($image_path))[0];
# Get the mime type
$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = $finfo->buffer($buffer);
# Load the image file
$image_file = new \Swift_Image($data, $filename, $mime_type);
# Set the disposition to inline
$image_file->setDisposition('inline');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use laravel, try to add `public_path()` at the  beginning of the path, e.g.:

```
<img src="<?php echo $message->embed(public_path().'/img/backend/name.jpg); ?>">
```